# Most efficient way to give certain output when string contains another string

Tags: python

I'm making a script in Python where it checks if a string contains one of the suits of card decks, since there's no switch/case and I couldn't really figure out how to do it with a dictionary, I'm kind of stumped.

Right now what I have is just 4 'if' statements in a row:

```py
def colorcheck(inp):
    if "Heart" in inp:
        return "Red"
    if "Diamond" in inp:
        return "Red"
    if "Club" in inp:
        return "Black"
    if "Spade" in inp:
        return "Black"
    return "Error"
```

It gives the right results, but I feel like this could be improved on a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
colors = {
    'Heart': 'Red',
    'Diamond': 'Red',
    'Club': 'Black',
    'Spade': 'Black',
}


def colorcheck(inp):
    for card, color in colors.items():
        if card in inp:
            return color
    return "Error"


print(colorcheck("Ace of Spades"))
```

**Output**:

```
Black
```